# How I use templates, databags and environments in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have templates with variables. these variables are in databags and and depend on the environment.
Example:

```
# Template
address =$foo

# Environment:
develoment

# Databag:
$foo = "sdfsdf"
```

How do I combine all of that?, I don't know where to put the information.

In template

```
address = "Http://ffff/dfg/"
```

I need to put here a variable

```
address = $pepe
```

In my databag in have the following data depending on the environment:

```
 $pepe = "Http://ffff/dfg/"
 $pepep ="Http://ffff/dewrwerw/
```

I don't know what I should write in the recipe.

Comment: could you please be more precise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Template:

```
address = <%= @pepe %>
```

Databag:

```
{
  "_default": {
    "pepe": "Http://ffff/dfg/"
  },
  "staging": {
    "pepe": "Http://ffff/staging"
  },
  "production": {
    "pepe": "Http://ffff/prod"
  }
}
```

Recipe:

```
data = data_bag_item( 'databagname', 'itemname' )

template '/path/to/file' do
  variables( pepe: data[node.chef_environment]['pepe'] )
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is a need, you are the best